# How do I upgrade from helm 3.0.0?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm currently running helm 3.0.0 in ubuntu and want to upgrade to helm > 3.0.2 [for gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab/-/commit/5f3b8d9e2c676ac7371e805ea130b7ccabd789ab). The [install instructions](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/) suggest it's as simple as deleting the helm binary and downloading the new one and the [release notes](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases) all suggest there are no breaking changes. Could it possibly be that simple?

Comment: are you having any issue?

Comment: I'm able to `helm version` and I get `...3.1.1`, but not sure how I can tell if anything broke

Comment: Helm, as of 3.0, is a purely client side tool. You upgrade it like you would any other CLI program on your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be that simple, provided you put the binary in the right place in your path (i.e. replace the one that you already get from `which helm`, assuming you're on unix).

You could test it by running some of the following helm commands:

- `helm version` will tell you what you're running.
- `helm list` will
  tell you what you have installed in your cluster (add `-n
  <namespace>` for a different namespace)

If you're ok to temporarily install something into the cluster, [follow a helm example to install something](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#helm-install-installing-a-package) and then delete it again with a `helm delete`